# Pandas - Loop through sheets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 5 sheets and created a script to do numerous formatting, I tested it per sheet, and it works perfectly.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
           
FileLoc = r'C:\T.xlsx'
Sheets = ['Alex','Elvin','Gerwin','Jeff','Joshua',]

df = pd.read_excel(FileLoc, sheet_name= 'Alex', skiprows=6) 
df = df[df['ENDING'] != 0]
df = df.head(30).T
df = df[~df.index.isin(['Unnamed: 2','Unnamed: 3','Unnamed: 4','ENDING' ,3])]
df.index.rename('STORE', inplace=True)
df['index'] = df.index

df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['index', 2 ,0, 1] ,value_name='SKU' )
df2 = df2[df2['variable']!= 3]

df2['SKU2'] = np.where(df2['SKU'].astype(str).fillna('0').str.contains('ALF|NOB|MET'),df2.SKU, None)
df2['SKU2'] = df2['SKU2'].ffill()
df2 = df2[~df2[0].isnull()]
df2 = df2[df2['SKU'] != 0]

df2[1] = pd.to_datetime(df2[1]).dt.date
df2.to_excel(r'C:\test.xlsx', index=False)
```

but when I assigned a list in `Sheet_name = Sheets` it always produced an error `KeyError: 'ENDING'`. This part of the code:

```
Sheets = ['Alex','Elvin','Gerwin','Jeff','Joshua',]
df = pd.read_excel(FileLoc,sheet_name='Sheets',skiprows=6)
```

Is there a proper way to do this, like looping?

My expected result is to execute the formatting that I have created and consolidate it into one excel file.

NOTE: All sheets have the same format.

[image]

Comment: @АлексейР -- Thanks for the reply but  it's not working, I got this error `KeyError: 'ENDING`

Comment: Read the sheet using :
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(FileLoc, sheet_name= None)
Access using:
sheet = sheets_dict['Alex']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In using the `read_excel` method, if you give the parameter `sheet_name=None`, this will give you a `OrderedDict` with the sheet names as keys and the relevant DataFrame as the value. So, you could apply this and loop through the dictionary using `.items()`.

The code would look something like this,

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('your-excel.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
for key, value in dfs.items():
  # apply logic to value
```

If you wish to combine the data in the sheets, you could use `.append()`. We can append the data after the logic has been applied to the data in each sheet. That would look something like this,

```
combined_df = pd.DataFrame()
dfs = pd.read_excel('your-excel.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
for key, value in dfs.items():
  # apply logic to value, which is a DataFrame
  combined_df = combined_df.append(sheet_df)
```

Comment: sorry i'm not familiar with the loop .. where will I put the Key and Value in my DF ?
` for key, value in dfs.items():`
     `df=pd.read_excel(FileLoc,sheet_name= 'Alex', `
              `df = df[df['ENDING']!= 0]`
                `df = df.head(30).T`

Comment: When you use `dfs = pd.read_excel('your-excel.xlsx', sheet_name=None)`, all of the sheets will be read and you will have a dictionary like object where the keys are the sheet names and the values are DataFrames for each sheet. As a result, when you do `for key, value in dfs.items():`, `key` will be your sheet name and `value` will be your DataFrame. So, then you can just apply your logic to `value`, which is the DataFrame for that sheet. Does that make sense?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm trying to assign a column for sheet name `value['Sales Man'] = key` why is not working  `dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: Alex`?

Comment: btw it's working but I'm still having this error `KeyError: 'ENDING'`

Comment: Is `ENDING` a column that is available in your Excel sheets? A `KeyError` is raised when the column is not available.

Comment: yes.. a column `df = df[df['ENDING'] != 0]`

Comment: Hmm.. Is there any way that I can take a look at your Excel sheet? It is difficult to say what the issue is otherwise.

Comment: I added the excel screenshot above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238758/discussion-between-minura-punchihewa-and-trunks).